# Import Python class from module but not dependencies

Tags: python, python-module

How can I import a python class but avoid running the import statement in that module?

```
Module foo
    from bar import A

Module bar
    import alpha

    class A(object):
        ...

    class B(objects):
        ...
```

I want to import class A but don't need class B. The import statement in the module bar is required for class B but I'd like to avoid needing to install that dependency if possible, as (I assume) it will be loaded into memory but not used.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't stop `bar` from importing `alpha` without hacking around in its source. But you can "fake out" `alpha`, by writing it into `sys.modules`:

```
>>> import alpha
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named alpha
>>> import sys; sys.modules['alpha'] = object()
>>> import alpha
>>>
```

This works because Python caches imported modules in `sys.modules`, so that if you import something twice you don't have to go through all the hard work the second time. Adding `alpha` to it means that Python thinks you have already imported `alpha`, so when `bar` tries to do so it will just get back the cached copy.

Obviously, you should think carefully about whether you are comfortable doing this -- `bar` will crash in unexpected ways if it actually uses `alpha` anywhere.

Comment: thanks - I was trying to use sys.modules but didn't realise I had to do an import

Comment: @alan a good rule of thumb is that __you need to define every variable__. For example, `sys` doesn't mean anything unless you tell Python "I want `sys` to mean the module in the stdlib", which you do with `import sys`.

Answer (score 1):

put the import in class B init

```
class B:
    def __init__:
        import alpha
```

If im not mistaken this might work

Comment: not if alpha is used in a B method or to provide decorators to be used on either B or on B methods.

Comment: Indeed, this will scope `alpha` to be inside of `__init__` so it can't be referenced anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem already:

There is a target module:

```py
# target_module.py

import module_1
import module_2
import module_3

def function_1():
    result_1 = module_1.some_function_1()
    return result_1

def function_2():
    result_2 = module_2.some_function_2()
    return result_2

def function_3():
    result_3 = module_3.some_function_3()
    return result_3
```

In the current environment, I don't have the `module_1` and `module_2` libraries, however I want to reuse the `function_3` that doesn't depend on `module_1` and `module_2`

So I create a utility function:

```py
def import_without(module, excluded_imports):
    while True:
        try:
            return importlib.import_module(module)
        except ModuleNotFoundError as e:
            if e.name in excluded_imports:
                sys.modules[e.name] = Mock()
                continue
            raise e
```

And use it in the following way:

```py
target_module = import_without('target_module_name', excluded_imports={'module_1', 'module_2'})
target_module.function_3()
```

This way you don't need to install the `module_1` and `module_2` in the current environment.