# importing module without importing that models imports

Tags: python, import

I am trying to import a python module without importing the imports of that module. I was digging around a bit, but the only way to exclude any command from being run when a file is being imported is the `if __name__ == "__main__":`
But the module is also imported by various other modules that ened that modules imports, so I cant place the imports below the  `if __name__ == "__main__":`
Any idea how to solve that?

The reason why I dont want to import this modules imports that those modules get run also from a jar jython envioronment and import java.lang functions. I just need to access a few functions in that file without the whole and importing those modules break make script. The functions that I am trying to access dont need any dependencies that module ahs.

I import via 'from moduleX import f1,f2,f3'

Comment: What's the use case? Why are you trying to avoid importing the dependencies (and how do you expect the module to work without them)?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're looking to accomplish?

Comment: How are you importing the module?  For example `import module`, `from module import *`, `from module import a, b, c` etc.

Comment: Don't put code with side-effects in module scope.  If the code is all bundled in functions and objects, you shouldn't have any problems importing modules.  I will reiterate though that without details of your particular code, it's hard to give any specific answers.

Comment: thanks for the follow up, edited my description

Comment: What you're asking is pretty complicated. Would it not be simpler to break up the module you're trying to import into two separate modules: those which access `java.lang.*` and those which don't?

Comment: Wait, are you trying to import a module written in jython that uses java snippets in to a CPython program?  You can't do that unless you do some significant reengineering to check which platform you are running under and load different dependencies dynamically in the module you are attempting to import.

Comment: unfortunately, I cant separate them as this is sued by another process which I cant modify.
The script I am trying to access is itself a python script, but is initially supposed to be run in connection with a jar process

Comment: Can you make __any__ changes to the module you're trying to import?

Comment: You can't use Java dependent Jython code in CPython any more than you can use C-extension dependent Python code in Jython.  If you have a combination of platform agnostic and platform specific code in a module, you need to break up or otherwise modify that module if you want to use the agnostic components from a program running on the other platform.  Note that you can leave the interface of the module the same for any Jython code that is using it so you won't break any existing dependent code, as long as you are able to modify the module itself.

Comment: Do you have control of the offending module? The pieces you need could be broken into a separate module, say 'module_utils.py'. moduleX.py could import module_utils.py so other users don't break and you could import module_utils.py.

Comment: Or, assuming this is a Jython/CPython interoperability issue, you could just use `platform.system()` and/or `platform.python_implementation()` to detect what you are running under and branch the code in the module directly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import Python class from module but not dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330588/import-python-class-from-module-but-not-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use import hooks to work around the issue. The `sys.meta_path` variable is a list of importers that can override the normal import processing. You can use them to stub out modules that only exist in Jython. Here's an example:

```
import types, sys

class Stub(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self

class StubModule(types.ModuleType):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return Stub()

class StubJavaImporter(object):
    def find_module(self, fullname, path = None):
        if fullname == 'java' or fullname.startswith('java.'):
            return self
        else:
            return None

    def load_module(self, fullname):
        mod = sys.modules.setdefault(fullname, StubModule(fullname))
        mod.__file__ = "<%s>" % self.__class__.__name__
        mod.__loader__ = self
        mod.__path__ = []
        mod.__package__ = fullname
        return mod

sys.meta_path.append(StubJavaImporter())
```

After running this code you can import any module starting with `java.` and access any attribute path within. For example:

```
In [2]: from java.lang import Object

In [3]: Object.equals
Out[3]: <__main__.Stub at 0x14d8b90>

In [4]: Object
Out[4]: <__main__.Stub at 0x14d8b90>

In [5]: Object.foo.bar.baz
Out[5]: <__main__.Stub at 0x14d8b90>
```

This might be enough to make things work. It is a *nasty, nasty* hack, but if you really can't modify the offending module this might be the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. You have to mock the modules/packages that you don't want to import.

The module you want to use:

```py
# target_module.py

import module_1
import module_2

def function_1():
    result = module_1.some_function()
    return result

def function_2():
    result = module_2.some_function()
    return result
```

In the current environment, we don't have the `module_1` libraries. However I want to reuse the `function_2` that doesn't depend on `module_1`.

So I create a utility function:

```py
def import_without(module, excluded_imports):
    while True:
        try:
            return importlib.import_module(module)
        except ModuleNotFoundError as e:
            if e.name in excluded_imports:
                sys.modules[e.name] = Mock()
                continue
            raise e
```

And use it in the following way:

```py
target_module = import_without('target_module_name', excluded_imports={'module_1'})
target_module.function_2()
```

This way you don't need to install the `module_1` in the current environment.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use `from module import *` and not include everything imported within `module` then you should define the variable `__all__` in `module`. This variable should be a list of strings naming the classes, variables, modules, etc. that should be imported.

From the python documentation

> If the list of identifiers is replaced by a star (`*`), all public names defined in the module are bound in the local namespace of the import statement

and

> The public names defined by a module are determined by checking the module’s namespace for a variable named `__all__`; if defined, it must be a sequence of strings which are names defined or imported by that module. The names given in `__all__` are all considered public and are required to exist.  If `__all__` is not defined, the set of public names includes all names found in the module’s namespace which do not begin with an underscore character (`_`) *[...]* **It is intended to avoid accidentally exporting items that are not part of the API (such as library modules which were imported and used within the module)**. *(emphasis mine)*

Comment: This doesn't seem to be his problem.  Whether or not an attribute is brought in to the namespace of the importing module, all the code in the module scope of the imported module will be executed, and if any of it is incompatible with the current platform, it will cause everything to blow up.  That seems to be the problem the OP is having.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds very interesting. But I think in my case, this would not help as other modules importing this module need the dependencies. So I need a way to modify the import statement in the importing module